# dev_appserver using goroot 1.6 instead of 1.8

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sdk, dev-appserver

I just updated google-cloud-sdk, and now dev_appserver is using goroot 1.6 instead of 1.8 so a bunch of stuff is not being recognised. Have looked all over the place, how do I tell dev_appserver to use goroot 1.8 instead of 1.6 ? It seems incredibly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The Go App Engine SDK uses 1.6, there is no way to run a higher Go version in App Engine.</strike> Their systems are finely tuned to work with a specific version and subset of features. A large production environment like App Engine has to go through an enormous amount of R&D to push new SDK versions. You just have to wait for new versions to trickle out and use what is available.

That said, if you really need to use a newer version of Go, you can always spin up a Compute Engine server, but you lose all the convenience of the standard or flex environments like auto scaling.

EDIT: As of June 27, 2017 they have enabled Go 1.8 as BETA in the SDK. See info in the release notes here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/release-notes

> June 27, 2017
>
> Go runtime notes
>
> Updated Go SDK to version 1.9.55 Enable the Go 1.8 beta This release
>   adds beta support for go1.8. To use Go 1.8, set api_version: go1.8 in
>   your app.yaml configuration file. You must also use App Engine SDK,
>   not Cloud SDK. To download the App Engine SDK, go to the Downloads
>   page and at the bottom of the page, expand the Or, you can download
>   the original App Engine SDK for Go section.

But notice that even as of Oct 3, 2017 they still call 1.8 beta.

> October 3, 2017
>
> Updated Go SDK to 1.9.59 Fixed bug in dev_appserver.py which used
>   incorrect build constraints for the Go 1.8 beta.

EDIT2: After a little tinkering, don't be alarmed if `goapp version` still prints `1.6.4`, it defaults to this. You have to be in the directory with the `app.yaml` with `api_version: go1.8` or it won't show. The `goapp` in the base directory is a script that parses the `app.yaml` to determine which version to use.

Comment: That's quite a surprise. Under google-cloud-sdk > platform > google_appengine I see both "goroot1.6" and "goroot1.8" so I assumed both was supported.

Comment: @KieranW. No, thank YOU! I'm glad you noticed this, now I can start migrating my own projects over to participate in the beta.